# gulp-connect developer server give no response when connect-history-api-fallback is used in middleware

Tags: gulp

I’m trying to use 'connect-history-api-fallback' with gulp-connect like this:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
connect = require('gulp-connect'),
historyApiFallback = require('connect-history-api-fallback');

gulp.task('server', function() {
    connect.server({
        root: 'app',
        livereload: true,
        middleware: function(connect, opt) {
            return [ historyApiFallback ];
        }
    });
});
```

However, the server http://localhost:8080/ gives no response. No errors in the terminal, merely get timeout in browser.
When I remove middleware like bellow, everything is perfect:

```
gulp.task('server', function() {
    connect.server({
        root: 'app',
        livereload: true
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The API has changed.
The correct way of using connect-history-api-fallback now the following:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
connect = require('gulp-connect'),
historyApiFallback = require('connect-history-api-fallback');

gulp.task('server', function() {
    connect.server({
        root: 'app',
        livereload: true,
        middleware: function(connect, opt) {
            return [ historyApiFallback({}) ];
        }
    });
});
```